# Can I overdraw my cashapp card?

Tags: united-states, cash, money-market, balance, overdraft

Can I overdraw my cashapp card if it starts with a positive balance to buy diapers and food and Walmart? I have $1.09 on my card and laid off right now. I have no 211 resources anywhere near my area.

Comment: Likely the transaction won't go through if it exceeds the available balance, but I'm not familiar with cashapp cards. Your best bet for immediate needs might be local food banks/churches.

Answer (score -1):

[EDIT] Removing the link [/EDIT]
There are cards that allow overdrafts in some form but CashApp is not one of them. Their Terms Of Service say that either the money has to be in their account or the user has to be connected to another account to fund the purchase.

Comment: Links to Google search queries aren't very helpful in answers, as results will change over time. Perhaps you can quote from a specific relevant source based on your search results?